# Reading a txt. in the format of (int float float string) and putting the values into parallel arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, file-io, char

```
1 42.4 73.45 Albany, N.Y.
2 35.05 106.39 Albuquerque, N.M.
3 35.11 101.5 Amarillo, Tex.
4 61.13 149.54 Anchorage, Alaska
5 33.45 84.23 Atlanta, Ga.
6 30.16 97.44 Austin, Tex.
```

Given a table like this in a .txt file in the format of int float float string, i have to read the file and put the data into correspoding arrays.

The data must be entered into parallel arrays where

- column 1 is the cityid
- column 2 is the x poistion
- column 3 is the y position
- column 4 is the city name

I can read the array but I don't know how i would put the data into the corresponding array.

i have tried using

```
while ((fscanf(filePtr, "%d %f %f %[^'\n']", cityid, x_location, y_location, city_name)) == 4)
```

but the loop goes through the entire file and only puts the very last entry into the array.

so i tried this loop

```
while (fscanf(filePtr, "%d %f %f %[^'\n']", tcityid, tx_location, ty_location, cityname) == 4)

    {
        cityid[i] = tcityid;

        x_location[i] = tx_location;

        y_location[i] = ty_location;

        *city_name[i] = cityname;           

    }
```

so my thinking is that the fscanf will read one line and put into the each of the values into the corresponding variable then copy it to the array. My code will build and run but when it reaches the while loop it throws an error that says

An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

I think the issue is with the `city_name`, I'm not really sure how to deal it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that scanf does not accept regular expressions in the format specification. Also, you cannot just simply use %s, because that stops at the first whitespace, so the state name would be cut off. The best I can suggest is that you read in a line using fgets() into a string named, say, 'line'. Then use sscanf to extract the first three numbers. Afterwards use strchr 3 times to find the 3rd space, that's where the city name starts. Finally use strdup() to make a copy of the city name that you can store in your array. You can't simply save the pointer into 'line' as line will be overwritten each time you read in a new line.

Comment: Forgot to mention: this is just an outline. In real code you ought to protect against buffer overruns when the data is malformed. String operations are notoriously easy to mess up and make it easy to create security holes...

Comment: we aren't allowed to use functions in string.h, but i was able to figure it out using fgets(). Pulling out the individual lines made it alot easier for me to understand what i needed to do thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong parameters passed to `fscanf()`.

I am surprised your compiler did not warn of this.  Check compiler settings or consider a new compiler.

Pass the *address* of `int`, `float` values.

Also amend `[]` specifier.

```
// while (fscanf(filePtr, "%d %f %f %[^'\n']", 
//   tcityid, tx_location, ty_location, cityname) == 4)
while (fscanf(filePtr, "%d %f %f %[^\n]", 
  &tcityid, &tx_location, &ty_location, cityname) == 4)
```

---

BTW [@LaszloLadanyi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33839196/2410359) idea is good to use `fgets()` to read the line and then use `sscanf()`.